# Ambiguous field in sql query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

i'm getting the following error when trying to filter a query by ID:

[image: Error message]

> My query:

```
 $film=film::wherehas('actor', function($q) use($actor_id){
        $q->where('actor_id','=', $actor_id);
      })->get();
```

> model Film:

```
class film extends Model{
    protected $table = "film";  
    protected $primaryKey = 'film_id';
    public $timestamps = false;
    use HasFactory;
    protected $sql=['film_id', 'title', 'length'];
}
```

[image: Relationship between tables]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query doesn't know which `actor_id` column you're targeting in that `where()` clause. Append the table name, like:

```php
$q->where('film_actor.actor_id', '=', $actorId);
// or `actors.actor_id`, not sure which is being expected here.
```

Or considering changing your `actors` table's `actor_id` to just `id`. Generally, you don't append the table name to `id` for the primary key. Same with `films.film_id`; that can just be `id`.

Answer (score 2):

Just change your query to be like:

```
$film=film::wherehas('actor', function($q) use($actor_id){
    $q->where('film_actor.actor_id','=', $actor_id);
})->get();
```